# uploading a .yml file to graphql in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to upload a yml file to a graphql end point through post method and getting the following error in JMeter,

Error Details:

http status code : 400

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>BadRequestError: Missing multipart field ‘operations’ (https://github.com/jaydenseric/graphql-multipart-request-spec).<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Busboy.&lt;anonymous&gt; (/app/node_modules/graphql-upload/public/processRequest.js:329:11)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:421:28)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Busboy.emit (events.js:327:22)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Busboy.emit (/app/node_modules/busboy/lib/main.js:37:33)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at /app/node_modules/busboy/lib/types/multipart.js:304:17<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11)</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Request payload details in body section:

```
------file_upload_for_schema
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="operations"

{"operationName":"fSchemaCreate","variables":{"record":{"name":"jam_test","file":null}},"query":"mutation fSchemaCreate($record: CreateOnefSchemaInput!) {\n  fSchemaCreate(record: $record) {\n    recordId\n    __typename\n  }\n}\n"}
------file_upload_for_schema
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="map"
{"1":["variables.record.file"]}
------file_upload_for_schema
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="1"; filename="conferenceImage.yml"
Content-Type: application/x-yaml
------file_upload_for_schema--
```

[image]

[image]

Request header configuration:
[image]

Actual UI screen from my application:

[image]

From browser capture:
[image]

[image]

After edit I am still facing the issue;

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to remove everything from the "Body data" and configure the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler like this:

[image]

In general if the file upload works in browser you can simply record the associated request(s) using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html), just make sure to copy the file(s) you're going to upload to "bin" folder of your JMeter installation, this way JMeter will be able to properly generate the HTTP Request samplers along with the [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager)(s)

More information: [Recording File Uploads with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/recording-file-uploads-jmeter)

Comment: Thank you Dimitri for you suggestion, shall I keep the file upload as it is ?

Comment: I'm not sure about mime type, most probably it should be `text/yaml` or `application/x-yaml`

Comment: Dmitri, how to remove this char-set, content-transfer and content-type from the request payload

Answer (score 0):

Just adding to Dimitri's configuration, please remove the `Content-Type` from the header manager.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Jyoti, this worked after I removed `Content-Type` from the header manager.